# Redrawing container or individual, dynamic elements in GWT page?

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing a GWT app (I'm fairly new to GWT so this is a request for best practices; I haven't found any relevant answer on SO or elsewhere) where a timeline is required. This timeline (with descriptions, labels, interaction handles, and plots) resides in its own container (a [`Panel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html)).

```
          [<] [now] [>]             // Interaction (navigation)
          2007 2008 2009 2010       // Labels
          |    |    |    |
+ Group 1                           // Collapsible groups
- Group 2
  Item 2a  =====   ==               // Item with plots (plots are wrapped in container per Item)
  Item 2b    =====     ===  =
-Group 3
  Item 3a ===
  Item 3b      ===
```

Now, when user's navigate the timeline (using the button to move forward or backwards), I need to recalculate some elements of the layout:

- Labels need recalculating / repositioning
- Plots need recalculating / repositioning. Plots are based on a set of `Timeslot` elements (extends [`Widget`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html), attributes `dateStart` and `dateEnd`) which are already related to `Item`s which are related to `Group`s.

The collapsible panels are [`DisclosurePanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html)s.

As far as I can tell, I now have two options for handling navigation:

1. I can [`clear()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html#clear%28%29) the container panel and do a complete redraw. For this, I need to preserve the state (collapsed/expanded) for all groups. (Groups and items are static for the entire period, by the way!) This will give **one big redraw**.
2. I can let the plot containers (each `Item` has its own `TimeslotContainer` which is a [`FlowPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html)) hold a reference to all its `Timeslot`s and then let every `TimeslotContainer` redraw itself (i.e., filter and position relevant `Timeslot`s) based on the current timespan. This will give **several minor redraws** (one per `Item` per expanded `Group`), the advantage being that the `DisclosurePanel`s will be preserved, thus maintaining their own state.

I'm inclined to go with the second solution. But are there any best practices on this one? Am I missing some common gotchas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and implemented a version of the **second solution** under the original intention to try the first if the second did not perform sufficiently. (This was never realized, though, as the second solution performed highly satisfactorily.)

What I asked in the question was primarily references to *the GWT way* to do this. I still haven't found anything written regarding this issue and so suspect that nobody has missed such guidelines before :) To conclude my search, I will self-answer the question outlining the way I ended up implementing together with the (assumed) pros and cons. Thanks to [@Ümit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356594) for supporting my instincts. The following is in part intended to address the last paragraph in [@Ümit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034111/redrawing-container-or-individual-dynamic-elements-in-gwt-page/8036242#8036242) regarding the complexity of the draw methods.

---

I ended up letting `TimeslotContainer`s (the Panels containing `TimeSlot`s), `LabelPanel` (Panel with generated `HTML` elements), and `NavigationPanel` realize a simple interface:

```java
public interface IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents {
    public void periodChanged();
}
```

A simple `EventBus` handled the notification process on these `IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents` instances:

```java
public class EventBus {
    private static EventBus instance;

    private Set<IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents> receivers;

    private EventBus() {
        this.receivers = new HashSet<IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents>();
    }

    public static EventBus getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new EventBus();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void addReceiver(IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents receiver) {
        this.receivers.add(receiver);
    }

    public void notifyPeriodChanged() {
        for (IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents receiver : this.receivers) {
            receiver.periodChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever one of `TimeslotContainer`, `LabelPanel` or `NavigationPanel` were instantiated (once per page load, these objects are reused throughout the lifetime of the page) they made sure to subscribe to the `EventBus`:

```java
public class TimeslotContainer extends FlowPanel implements IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents {
    public TimeslotContainer(/* ... */) {
        // ...
        EventBus.getInstance().addReceiver(this);
    }
    // ...
}
```

In order to handle the "complex" draw method, I simply created a method (`buildFromStore()`) to add relevant `Widget`s (e.g., newly created `Timeslot` objects on the `TimeslotContainer`s). This resulted in great reuse of the draw method:

```java
public class NavigationPanel extends FlowPanel implements IReceivesPeriodChangedEvents {
    public NavigationPanel() {
        // ...
        buildFromStore();
        EventBus.getInstance().addReceiver(this);
    }

    private void buildFromStore() {
        // Add lots of HTML elements here
    }

    @Override
    public void periodChanged() {
        clear();
        buildFromStore();
    }
}
```

Simple as that!

---

**In conclusion:**
No gotchas encounted. Lots of minor redraws did not seem to be a problem (I never implemented solution one, though). The draw methods could be reused (in this case, at least). The collapsible `DisclosurePanel`s never lost their state as they were never replaced (only their contents were).

Comment: I like your approach.  
Just 3 comments: - Any reason why you didn't use one of GWT's EventBus (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html) implementations (i.e. SimpleEventBus)? You could use them as a local EventBus for your TimeslotContainer. 

- If your buildFromStore() method depdends on retrieving the sizes of containing/parent containers you might run into problems and have to defer the actual layout to the end (using Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()).
- You could also implement RequireResize interface for resizing events.

Comment: @Ümit Good questions! 1) Yes, that would have made sense to use an existing `EventBus`. However, I just needed the functionality now and will rewrite this code when the solution is plugged into the existing project (where we already use an enhanced `EventBus`). 2) and 3) The actual dimensions and placements are set in percentages and thus laid out according to the container via CSS. Therefore I am able to do all this without any hooks into resize handler etc. (I bet this is what made it all so simple in the end :) .)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I also like having dimensions as percentages (fluid/flexible design). However unfortunately sometimes this is not possible. For example if you use google visualization charts they require explicit pixel sizes and these have to be calculated dynamically. I ran into a lot of troubles until I stumbled over the code for the [HeaderPanel](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HeaderPanel.java&q=HeaderPanel%20package:http://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&type=cs). Just for the record if you run into the same problems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If groups and items are static I would also recommend the second approach.
DOM operations (constructing, etc) are properly the most expensive functions in a GWT application (performance wise) so these DOM operations should be kept at a minimum.
However I don't think performance may be a big issue here because the amount of DOM elements is relatively low.

Nevertheless I still think the second approach is better. You don't have to store the state for groups and items and as they are static it doesn't really make sense to redraw them.

I can only think of one advantage of the first approach: 
There will be only one relatively easy draw function. In the second approach all TimesSlotContainer have to implement a function in order to redraw themselves and also take into account position and context of the Timespan. That function might be more complicated then one big re-draw function.